# Parameter not passed to next page - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to pass a parameter to the next page onclick of a button.

I have tried as below; on the first page I have a textarea and I want to pass that value to the next page on button click using AngularJS, I have tried as below, but it's not working.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">
<head>
    <title>Angular: Service example</title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
        <script src="sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <input ng-model="thing.x"/>         
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="send" onclick="send()">

    <script>
        function send(){
            window.location ="second.html";
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**sample.js**

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */



var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);

projectModule.factory('theService', function() {  
    return {
        thing : {
            x : 100
        }
    };
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, theService) {
    $scope.thing = theService.thing;
    $scope.name = "First Controller";
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, theService) {   
    $scope.someThing = theService.thing; 
    $scope.name = "Second Controller!";
}
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Passed data</title>
        <script src="sample.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <input ng-model="someThing.x"/>             
    </div>

        <br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Please can you help me to figure it out?

Comment: When doing window.location="second.html", you're actually leaving the first page, thus angular will have no clue about any data you entered in the first page. I suggest you take a look at angular routing here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Further to the comment by @Dola when you leave the first page the entire app reloads (because you are using js window.location()), therefore theService is reloaded too and the value you set in FirstCtrl is lost.  As has been said, to get this working you need to deploy angular routing.

Comment: @lukkea-Please help me as i am newbie..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Remove **send()** function

```
function FirstCtrl($scope, $location, theService) {
    $scope.thing = theService.thing;
    $scope.name = "First Controller";
    $scope.send = function(){
       $location.path('/second').search({id: 12});
    };
}
```

---

```
<input type="button" value="send" ng-click="send()">
```

Comment: hello thank you for helping me,but when i click on button nothing is happening..:(

Comment: Move <input type="button" value="send" ng-click="send()"> inside the controller div tag

Comment: -its working on same page,I want to do the same thing to second page,So i want to remove that first html page you made..and when i click on button it should go to next page with entered value.

Comment: You can set first.html to load as the app loads. **[Default Controller]** Check now http://plnkr.co/edit/bDAIUtNkGMu3r9L7NdhW

Answer (score 0):

To send the parameter to next page you have to use `$location` service.

```
$location.path('/second').search({id: 12});
```

But again this will not work for you as you are not using AngularJS for routing , you are using JS for that. I suggest following this [PhoneCatApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to learn Angular basics

Comment: can you pls tell me which coding changes i have to do in my code ?pls pls